# Trying to curl a snake tail stl file in Blender

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I'm getting into 3D printing edit/design and learning blender. Right now I'm trying to figure out the best way to curl this snake's tail so that it spirals on the base platform. I've tried push/pull, sculpt and simple deform while selecting only the tail, but can't seem to figure out how to curl with the tip as the pull point basically.

Any tips here? Photo from cura so you can see the baseplate I'm trying to curl it around.
[image]

Comment: I would probably set up an armature, possibly with a bendy bone or two involved, and use that to deform it.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want to do something like this:

[image]

i would enable the add-on (if you didn't do that already)

[image]

and then add an archemedan spiral

[image]

change radius growth, turns and height to your needs:

[image]

i will now do this with a simple cylinder...because i don't have your model, but should work too ...

so i add a cylinder

[image]

press tab to enter edit mode

then G Z, hold CTRL, and move up so that it looks like this:

[image]

then select the upper vertices

[image]

G Z ->

[image]

CTRL - R, scroll mouse

[image]

Tab -> object mode

[image]

add modifier: curve like this:

[image]

[image]

looks not that nice...don't worry, you still can change anything...

so select your cylinder in object mode, move it on z like this:

[image]

And with S -> Shift Z -> like this:

[image]

and you still can change your cylinder in edit mode:

[image]

by selecting top vertices and click on "proportional editing" -> change proportional size by scrolling mouse wheel

result:

[image]